# Updating a web page to reflect deleted data from CRUD app without hard refresh

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I have a to-do app that functions - I can create an item, check off that it's been completed, and delete the item using an X button next to it.  When I create an item, it pops up immediately on the list.  But when I delete an item, I have to manually refresh the page for it to update.  What am I missing that would get it to update in real time?

index.html:

```
        const deletebtns = document.getElementsByClassName('deletebutton');
    
        for (let i = 0; i < deletebtns.length; i++) {
            const deletebutton = deletebtns[i];
            deletebutton.onclick = function(e) {
                const todoId = e.target.dataset['id'];
                fetch('/todos/' + todoId, {
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    });
                }
        }
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('/todos/<todo_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_todo(todo_id):
  try:
    Todo.query.filter_by(id=todo_id).delete()
    db.session.commit()
  except:
    db.session.rollback()
  finally:
    db.session.close()
  return jsonify({ 'success': True })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location.reload ();
```

Should do it.

If you call this method from anywhere in the web page, the web page will reload. This reload will occur through the web cache. What is a cache exactly? It’s a temporary space your browser reserves to store documents, images and other data that it retrieves from a server. Caching of data allows a browser to speed up your browsing and lets you reload often-visited sites faster.

You can change the default cache reload by setting a forceGet parameter. This will cause the browser to reload the webpage by fetching the data from the server anew instead of using the cache. This can be accomplished by using the following code:

```
location.reload(true);
```

By default, the value of the forceGet parameter is false. This means that the location.reload method always looks like this:

```
location.reload(false)
```